# Custom ToolBar without textarea of any Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to build own custom ToolBar with of Text Editors that contains Font types and Font size,Bold,Italics etc.
I referred many editors but i do not want the textarea of that editors.
What i need i have a textbox/textarea and a text inside it,so when i select particulat text,my custom tool bar should and can edit the content.
Is this thing possible in Javascript/JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Ask your question clearly.

If i'm right, i have understand that you want to edit the style of the text that you have selected with a custom toolbar. That's it ?

EDIT-------------------------------------

I can propose you this JS function who edit the first string occurence (I continue to search about fixing this problem) and put it in bold :

```js
function selected(){
  var highlight = window.getSelection();  

  var span = '<span style="font-weight:bold;">' + highlight + '</span>';

  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(highlight, span);
}
```

```html
 <div>
 Stack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test 
 Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test 
 sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf 
 OverflowStack Test Test Test sdf Overflow
 </div>
 <button onclick="selected();">Test</button>
```

Comment: ya,that's what i want only